# Interweaving two datasets

Tags: echarts

I want to display a chart with two datasets, one with status of "200 OK" and another one with all the others.

What I want is to interweave these two datasets, so one bar chart column is dataset1 and the next one might be from datset2.
I only managed to display both of them next to each other, with no possibility to filter them.
The legend should be shown and the user should be able to unselect one of the datasets.

This is the layout I intend to create:
[image]

And this is what I have:
[image]

[echarts fiddle](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?code=PYBwLglsB2AEC8sDeAoWsAeBBDEDOAXMmurGAJ4gCmRA5AMYCGYVA5sAE7m0kC-ANCXI58RVKTKUasWgDdGAGwCuVHugEkFbKtAAmYkujwALYAHciYDir6CjVDhCqFYAbUPEJ6Xc0Z4qYACS-jK6eACMtHZeFNR0AEaMHFEe6Dr0wLrS4l7oGHRKHAopuejkdBlK0GBqXhq5GQqcdBxUuiVeeGCM9ADWdF09vZEe9aQ5Ej7d_kEhtGEATB0SsdK0icnREumZ2amk-TKFxVte5TKV1bUSYxKNzTLxyqqnRt19A-_D17C8JAC60SmfgCRHcEgmpAA9FDYAAFDjAWQQLKwRiwGawYAAM1gwIAdPsUXRgTMAPocRhmZakXQQAC2OjwUGgLlctGOUQuwCqNX4MkGYCUeFogP2eB5HHo0nBpUhuWOdCRNIaPOqRHCAGZXp1ukKXLQFgAGI2wADyAGkfjcdeh5V5FTJWIwVV5LmAiAAWW2kQXCuieo2e2AAOWAYFgADE1e19uoffaJI7aGZsa67mqPbBwkafW9mP6ZIHg2GI9GqrHSr8E3HSMmAF4QdOkd1EACcbbzGL1hcNJvNVtrty8ibrRTovWgzfQrdgAA4512_QbjabLdbSMOIbX0MmMPXp7BZ22AGxLnsG4uh8NRmMb-O10e78cXEVd2cAdnC54Ll6D17LO8hxrKtnwUOh6ynd9My9b8d27X86FXAd72rR94OTABHPl4NncIPx_fUA3_UtbwrVCt3GDCXxTF5cJg2AAFYCPg5ckP7ddgPQ0DYGTchZEPWcTzgni2KLEib3LPQKJA0Dk3pdpoN5dtvVYi92LXQcq0ou1qPAmRoCUQSGNPQje2QzjtNkqtkzweljOU2BOzUxDxJLSSgKs7i5JoqgjKU9VYA_ZzRPUmQLK00odM8Hz9IYAArBzArbBYzJXDjItyaKn14mi8DTAKs3CM8XKI8KMpk7ybJoswQCSrMT0YtLiPcwDyK4qscqw1h6o1VLSvMiqh32f5RlOe1iVCCJXWxRF6QAEV8GZghJJaAgpKlXSsRhWWxTh6TBKrSlWOhsQgBQWE2ejoDO1gDB47wGSZFlPl_Q90FoeBaA0lD4L-LzOvgk6BU4HCeIyG6IDumKeLpRlWRe7leXerEOCyDgSWcehUPUYbclGm0PAmuZFhmubFumAIVtCNawA26kdW23b9sOwGeOB2gzouhxjMh6Gcse-HmRgV79RR2gAEIvp-yzQP-qLrOOqQBlB3nbvuh64eekWkauLt0E4dHMbwbG_rxrwCc3AEUF4ABuIA)

Answer (score 0):

The solution I thought of is this:

- create an invisible dataset `"ds0"`, that will contain all the items and whose transform performs the sorting - its only purpose is to set the position of the x label by the global sorting criterion; it will be invisible by virtue of its value being zero and its name being undefined (which excludes it from the legend).
- the other two datasets, `"ds1"` and `"ds2"` are stacked on top of this, will have the filter but no sorting, so they will be placed at the position dictated by `"ds0"`.

```js
const dom = document.getElementById("chart-container");
const myChart = echarts.init(dom, null, {
    renderer: "canvas",
    useDirtyRect: false
});

const option = {
    xAxis: {
        type: "category"
    },
    yAxis: {
        type: "value"
    },
    legend: {
        show: true
    },
    series: [
        {
            datasetId: "ds0",
            stack: "stack1",
            type: "bar",
            encode: {
                x: "url",
                y: "zero"
            }
        },
        {
            name: "200",
            datasetId: "ds1",
            type: "bar",
            encode: {
                x: "url",
                y: "count"
            },
            color: "red",
            stack: "stack1"
        },
        {
            name: "non-200",
            datasetId: "ds2",
            type: "bar",
            encode: {
                x: "url",
                y: "count"
            },
            color: "blue",
            stack: "stack1"
        }
    ],
    dataset: [
        {
            // Provide a set of data.
            id: "dataset_raw",
            dimensions: ["url", "count", "status", "zero"],
            source: [
                {
                    url: "ov",
                    count: 13,
                    status: "200 OK"
                },
                {
                    url: "ga",
                    count: 4,
                    status: "404 Not Found"
                },
                {
                    url: "wf",
                    count: 10,
                    status: "404 Not Found"
                },
                {
                    url: "zi",
                    count: 99,
                    status: "200 OK"
                },
                {
                    url: "kn",
                    count: 88,
                    status: "200 OK"
                },
                {
                    url: "xz",
                    count: 96,
                    status: "404 Not Found"
                },
                {
                    url: "cs",
                    count: 71,
                    status: "404 Not Found"
                },
                {
                    url: "zn",
                    count: 41,
                    status: "200 OK"
                },
                {
                    url: "qt",
                    count: 17,
                    status: "404 Not Found"
                },
                {
                    url: "we",
                    count: 57,
                    status: "200 OK"
                },
                {
                    url: "yv",
                    count: 61,
                    status: "404 Not Found"
                },
                {
                    url: "md",
                    count: 94,
                    status: "200 OK"
                },
                {
                    url: "nu",
                    count: 96,
                    status: "200 OK"
                },
                {
                    url: "sm",
                    count: 9,
                    status: "404 Not Found"
                },
                {
                    url: "eu",
                    count: 79,
                    status: "200 OK"
                },
                {
                    url: "cj",
                    count: 92,
                    status: "200 OK"
                },
                {
                    url: "sf",
                    count: 16,
                    status: "200 OK"
                },
                {
                    url: "wp",
                    count: 65,
                    status: "404 Not Found"
                },
                {
                    url: "qg",
                    count: 12,
                    status: "200 OK"
                }
            ].map((o) => ({ ...o, zero: 0 }))
        },
        {
            id: "ds0",
            fromDatasetId: "dataset_raw",
            transform: [
                {
                    type: "sort",
                    config: {
                        dimension: "count",
                        order: "desc"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            id: "ds1",
            fromDatasetId: "ds0",
            transform: [
                {
                    type: "filter",
                    config: {
                        dimension: "status",
                        "=": "200 OK"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            id: "ds2",
            fromDatasetId: "ds0",
            transform: [
                {
                    type: "filter",
                    config: {
                        dimension: "status",
                        "!=": "200 OK"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
};

if (option && typeof option === "object") {
    myChart.setOption(option);
}

window.addEventListener("resize", myChart.resize);
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#chart-container {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="chart-container"></div>
<script src="https://fastly.jsdelivr.net/npm/echarts@5.4.2/dist/echarts.min.js"></script>
```

(the same in a [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/apache-echarts-demo-forked-k31yvi?file=/index.js))

I'm thinking that maybe a more elegant solution can be found to set the height of `ds0` bars to zero, that is more elegant than mine that consists on adding a `"zero": 0` entry to each datapoint. I'd be glad to edit if a suggestion is offered.